# How to use Oauth Grant Type Password in Mulesoft?

Tags: oauth-2.0, mulesoft, raml, anypoint-platform

I need to use OAUTH Password Grant type in my project. Please help.

## mulesoft

I need to use username password in OAuth

> How to Use HTTP Request Connector:
> Use an HTTP Request connector to send a POST request to the token URL of your OAuth provider. This request should include the username, and the password in the request body. The response will contain the access token.
>
> Handle the Access Token:
> Once you receive the access token, you can store it securely in a session, database, or some other storage mechanism. This token will be used to access protected resources on behalf of the user.
>
> Access Protected Resources:
> With the access token, you can include it in the Authorization header of subsequent requests to the protected resources to authenticate and access the data.

Comment: Using hashtags inside questions does nothing. There is a separate field for tags. You seem to be asking about Mule applications but didn't mention that in the question nor in the tag list. MuleSoft is not the same as Mule runtime. You seem to be doing an exercise type of question. Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. It is a questions & answers site. You have to provide what you have researched, tried and the results. Also you most likely need to split the question into more specific questions. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also please read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems.